# JMeter: What is difference between Loop Count in Thread Group and Loop Controller in Logic Controller

Tags: multithreading, loops, controller, logic, jmeter

I would like to know in what scenario I can use:
1. Loop Count in Thread Group and 
2. Loop Controller in Logic Controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Loop count, it will loop all the requests in the thread group where as using the loop controller you can loop specific requests inside the thread group.